# MySQL BIGINT incorrectly Truncating with 0

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert large numbers into a MySQL version 5.6 database. Inserts are executed without error, however, the inserted value is incorrect.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.test;
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (
    longnumber BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO dbo.test VALUES(
    1024831220230717441
)

SELECT longnumber FROM dbo.test; #returns 1024831220230717400
```

Comment: Weird. Every source I'm reading shows the max value should be `9223372036854775807`, which is considerably larger than the number you provided.

Comment: Indeed. According to the official documentation, the largest number you have stated is correct. I have tried also using an unsigned BIGINT, with a maximum value of 18446744073709551615 with no change of outcome.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1b8e1 same results. tried to insert `1024831220230717399` and it gave the same `1024831220230717400` result.

Comment: Very strange. I tried this on an IIS7 server running MySQL 5.6 using MySQL command line, phpMyAdmin and PHP7 and it works fine on all 3 for both 1024831220230717441 and 1024831220230717399.